# Gas Range, Ductless Range Hood, No Window

Tags: carbon-monoxide

Curious of all's opinion regarding the use of a "ductless" vent hood with a gas range stove/oven. This concerns me a lot- mostly due to the risk of CO poisoning. However, researching my state's code and other literature I believe this set up is authorized.

That being said, I have three questions:

(1) I have a CO monitor in each bedroom one in the living room. [for context its a small 2 BR house, 1 floor]. Would you advise I put a CO monitor in the kitchen as well, or will that just go off constantly?

(2) The window does not open in the kitchen unfortunately. But, a door to the deck from kitchen does. I am thinking about leaving the door slightly open when cooking for natural ventilation. I could also get a HarborFreight portable ventilator to blow out the door. Would you have concerns of this "backdrafting" the furnace?

(3) From a general sense, why are gas ranges allowed without external ventilation? Is that because they don't produce enough CO to be deadly if in normal operating condition and used just for cooking?

Comment: Normal operating condition is the key.  Lately CO production seems to minor compared to other non-deadly gases they produce in a home.  As long as the flame is nice and blue with only a very tiny tip of yellow, you should be good for CO not being produced

Comment: Opinion is that regardless of stove type, ductless hoods are a useless sham. With gas they are just a more concerning useless sham. Punch a duct out the wall...

Comment: To be fair, they can catch a tiny bit of flying grease, but otherwise useless for steam, etc.